# Не могу найти элемент по XPath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Добрый день, я только учусь использовать Selenium WebDriver + Java.
Никак не могу найти элемент по XPath.
Необходимо:
1) создать письмо mail.ru
2) сохранить в черновики
3) зайти в папку черновики и проверить что оно действительно там

первые 2 шага у меня получились, а вот с третьим, у меня получается зайти в папку черновики, и я пытаюсь найти свое письмо по адресату отправителя(заходить в само письмо не нужно, необходимо из папки черновики убедиться что там есть моё письмо).
Так вот, я составил уже около 5-6 разных xpath, и самое главное что в FireFox с помощью FirePath или FireFinder он находит его, а в WebDriver выдаёт NoSuclElementException.

К примеру вот несколько XPath:

```
//div[contains(text(),'webdriver@mail.ru')]
```

или

```
//a[@title='webdriver@mail.ru']
```

Повторюсь что в FirePath и FireFinder все находит отлично, а WebDriver выдаёт Exception.

Ах да, совсем забыл, в процессе поиска я думал что элемент находится во фрейме, может быть из за этого он не может найти. Но увы, я проверил html код, фреймов там нету.

Comment: Если я правильно все понял, то у mail.ru на странице с черновиками нигде не отображается email, а вы ищите как раз по нему, например если черновик создан для `test@test.com`, то на странице с черновиками будет отображаться что письмо предназначено для `test`, а не для `test@test.com`. В качестве другого пути я бы предложил вам брать первый элемент из списка черновиков

Comment: Может быть timing проблема - пробовали добавлять wait через `WebDriverWait()`?

Comment: Может быть Вам нужно дождаться окончания загрузки ajax за странице? Попробуйте [это](http://software-testing.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/32404-ozhidanie-zaversheniia-ajax-zaprosov-webdriver/).

Answer (score 1):

попробуй подождать простым Thread.Sleep(5000);
Если поможет -- однозначно проблема в недостаточности времени подгрузки и тогда нужно использовать более красивые решения вроде WebDriverWait() иль альтернатив.

Если нет, тогда покажи хтмл.

Answer (score 1):

Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой. У меня .Net, но, думаю, решение похожее.

1. я добавил ожидание.
2. письмо ищу не по адресу, а первое в списке.
3. Далее, используя ожидание, я нахожу и кликаю по верхнему письму.

код:

```
//1
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
//2
string savedMail = "(//div[@class='b-datalist__item__addr'])[1]";
//3
IWebElement savedMailAddressee = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(savedMail)));     
                CheckElementPresent(true, savedMail);
                savedMailAddressee.Click();
```